# How do I get the divs to move around constantly? The array values don't seem to update when random is called

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

What I want to happen is have a while(True) loop which constantly moves the divs around until a button is clicked to break out of it, although of course the DOM doesn't update the way i would like it too!

```html
<div className="bg-[#151A1D] place-items-center grid grid-cols-5 grid-rows-3 gap-3 h-screen w-screen">
          {/* {toparrnew.map((topy, index) => ( */}
          <>
            <div id="box0" className={`transition-all duration-700 absolute bg-[#F8F3F4] w-[300px] h-[300px]`} style={{ top: toparrnew[0], left: leftarrnew[0] }} >
              <Canvas className="canvas">
                <OrbitControls enableZoom={true} /> //allows 3d rotation, also says no zooming!
                <ambientLight intensity={0.5} /> //adds light, stops it from being black
                <directionalLight position={[-2, 5, 2]} intensity={1} /> // //adds light to give it 3D Effect
                <Boxy />
              </Canvas>
            </div>
            <div id="box1" className={`transition-all duration-700 absolute bg-[#F8F3F4] w-[300px] h-[300px]`} style={{ top: toparrnew[1], left: leftarrnew[1] }} >
              <Canvas className="canvas">
                <OrbitControls enableZoom={true} /> //allows 3d rotation, also says no zooming!
                <ambientLight intensity={0.5} /> //adds light, stops it from being black
                <directionalLight position={[-2, 5, 2]} intensity={1} /> // //adds light to give it 3D Effect
                <Boxy />
              </Canvas>
            </div>
            <div id="box2" className={`transition-all duration-700 absolute bg-[#F8F3F4] w-[300px] h-[300px]`} style={{ top: toparrnew[2], left: leftarrnew[2] }} >
              <Canvas className="canvas">
                <OrbitControls enableZoom={true} /> //allows 3d rotation, also says no zooming!
                <ambientLight intensity={0.5} /> //adds light, stops it from being black
                <directionalLight position={[-2, 5, 2]} intensity={1} /> // //adds light to give it 3D Effect
                <Boxy />
              </Canvas>
            </div>
            <div id="box3" className={`transition-all duration-700 absolute bg-[#F8F3F4] w-[300px] h-[300px]`} style={{ top: toparrnew[3], left: leftarrnew[3] }} >
              <Canvas className="canvas">
                <OrbitControls enableZoom={true} /> //allows 3d rotation, also says no zooming!
                <ambientLight intensity={0.5} /> //adds light, stops it from being black
                <directionalLight position={[-2, 5, 2]} intensity={1} /> // //adds light to give it 3D Effect
                <Boxy />
              </Canvas>
            </div>
            <div id="box4" className={`transition-all duration-700 absolute bg-[#F8F3F4] w-[300px] h-[300px]`} style={{ top: toparrnew[4], left: leftarrnew[4] }} >
              <Canvas className="canvas">
                <OrbitControls enableZoom={true} /> //allows 3d rotation, also says no zooming!
                <ambientLight intensity={0.5} /> //adds light, stops it from being black
                <directionalLight position={[-2, 5, 2]} intensity={1} /> // //adds light to give it 3D Effect
                <Boxy />
              </Canvas>
            </div>
            <div id="box5" className={`transition-all duration-700 absolute bg-[#F8F3F4] w-[300px] h-[300px]`} style={{ top: toparrnew[5], left: leftarrnew[5] }} >
              <Canvas className="canvas">
                <OrbitControls enableZoom={true} /> //allows 3d rotation, also says no zooming!
                <ambientLight intensity={0.5} /> //adds light, stops it from being black
                <directionalLight position={[-2, 5, 2]} intensity={1} /> // //adds light to give it 3D Effect
                <Boxy />
              </Canvas>
            </div>
            <div id="box6" className={`transition-all duration-700 absolute bg-[#F8F3F4] w-[300px] h-[300px]`} style={{ top: toparrnew[6], left: leftarrnew[6] }} >
              <Canvas className="canvas">
                <OrbitControls enableZoom={true} /> //allows 3d rotation, also says no zooming!
                <ambientLight intensity={0.5} /> //adds light, stops it from being black
                <directionalLight position={[-2, 5, 2]} intensity={1} /> // //adds light to give it 3D Effect
                <Boxy />
              </Canvas>
            </div>
            <div id="box7" className={`transition-all duration-700 absolute bg-[#F8F3F4] w-[300px] h-[300px]`} style={{ top: toparrnew[7], left: leftarrnew[7] }} >
              <Canvas className="canvas">
                <OrbitControls enableZoom={true} /> //allows 3d rotation, also says no zooming!
                <ambientLight intensity={0.5} /> //adds light, stops it from being black
                <directionalLight position={[-2, 5, 2]} intensity={1} /> // //adds light to give it 3D Effect
                <Boxy />
              </Canvas>
            </div>
            <div id="box8" className={`transition-all duration-700 absolute bg-[#F8F3F4] w-[300px] h-[300px]`} style={{ top: toparrnew[8], left: leftarrnew[8] }} >
              <Canvas className="canvas">
                <OrbitControls enableZoom={true} /> //allows 3d rotation, also says no zooming!
                <ambientLight intensity={0.5} /> //adds light, stops it from being black
                <directionalLight position={[-2, 5, 2]} intensity={1} /> // //adds light to give it 3D Effect
                <Boxy />
              </Canvas>
            </div>
            <div id="box9" className={`transition-all duration-700 absolute bg-[#F8F3F4] w-[300px] h-[300px]`} style={{ top: toparrnew[9], left: leftarrnew[9] }} >
              <Canvas className="canvas">
                <OrbitControls enableZoom={true} /> //allows 3d rotation, also says no zooming!
                <ambientLight intensity={5} /> //adds light, stops it from being black
                <directionalLight position={[-2, 5, 2]} intensity={1} /> // //adds light to give it 3D Effect
                <Boxy />
              </Canvas>
            </div>
            <div className="col-start-1 col-span-5 row-start-2">
              <Button title="PLAY" onPress={() => { controles() }}></Button>
            </div>
            <button id="clicky" className="display:none" onClick={() => {console.log("aa")}}></button>
          </>
          {/* ))} */}
        </div>
```

Above is my return code below is the code from my function which is called

```
  const controlHelper = async () => {
    findRandom();
  }

  const controles = async () => {
    thisFunc()
    await sleep(1000);
    setFloatingTime(false);
    await sleep(1000);
    // controlHelper();
    controlHelper();
  }
```

It works when I click a button, of course because the DOM is refreshing, although I have no idea how to do it otherwise.

[Before pressing control](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7jUn0.png)

[After using control](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Mz9U.png)

Comment: Please provide a runnable example

Comment: @GarfieldKlon i can't do that but i have added some images which hopefully will help